# Onclick button -> retain color - is this possible using arrays?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, ejs

Using a php/ejs script; I would like a button to retain its hover color once clicked.  The script is running on Ajax, so the page doesn't refresh.

I got the color retention to work, but it defaults to the blank (0) / 'amount' class no matter which button I click on.

I also tried to hardcode IDs, to differentiate the classes and no success.

From the template file/ejs; my current code:

```
<% _.each(model.information_amounts, function(info) { %>
        <div class="classBlock"> 
                <button type="button" name="info" value="<%= info.amount ? info.amount : '' %>" id="info" class="amount"><%= info.name %></button>
        </div>
<% }) %>
```

^^ this loops through a set of arrays and displays all of the button options.

Have tried:

```
<% _.each(model.information_amounts, function(info) { %>            
      <div class="classBlock"> 
                <button type="button" name="info" value="<%= info.amount ? info.amount : '' %>" id="info" class="amount<%= info.id %>"><%= info.name %></button>            
      </div> 
<% }) %>
```

[ and hardcoded the stylesheet class for `amount1` and so on. ]

current Stylesheet:

```
 .amount {
     background-color:#c0c0c0;
}
.amount:hover, .amount:focus,.chosen {
     background-color:#000;
}
```

have also tried ajax directly in common.js:

```
$('#info').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('chosen');
});
```

Not sure if its relevant to the question, but here's the js event:

```
    events: {
        'click button#info': 'updateInfo',
},
```

Update:
Tried this, did not work.  Because the template is wrapped in EJS, do I need to do something special in order for this to work?  I mean, js rollovers and color changes are pretty basic.  Not sure why this isn't working.

Stylesheet:

```
  .amount1 {
     background-color:#c0c0c0;
  }
  .chosen1, .amount1:hover {
       background-color:#000;
  }
```

common.js 
Yes, it is being called from the page.  No errors in console:

```
 $('.amount').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('.chosen1');
});
```

Button input from the EJS template:

```
<button type="button" name="info" value="<%= info.amount ? info.amount : '' %>" id="info" class="amount<%= info.id %>"><%= info.name %></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what what happening:
- The *element* was being refreshed.
- I had to manipulate the session in php in order to pass a 'true' variable back to EJS in order to get the correct button to retain its color.

For those interested, here's what I did:
- Added a session variable in php to capture the button value:

```
$this->session->data['selectedamount'] = $this->session->data['amount'];
```

In EJS:

```
<% 
    if(model.successes.selectedamount !== info.amount){ 
        var chosenclass ='amount';
    }else{
        var chosenclass ='chosen';
    } 
%>
<button type="button" name="info" value="<%= info.amount ? info.amount : '' %>" id="info" class="<%= chosenclass %>"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the pseudo-class `:visited`. Put it in your CSS as a selector, and copy the color you used in `:hover`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

Comment: Tried this both with/without the hardcoded classes, no luck.  Since the page doesn't reload and it's not a link, is :visited still applicable in this regard?  It's not "visited" like clicking a href, for example.

Comment: @necrodeus - Ah, my bad. Are the buttons programmatically created? Your `.on('click')` is the right idea, why is it not working? What error are you getting? Is anything happening at all?

Comment: I updated my post.  No errors at all, which is what's making this such a struggle to figure out.

Comment: @necrodeus - Try `$(document).on('click', selector, function(){...});`. That should be able to side step the issue of programmatically generated buttons.

Comment: Gives the same result as my initial test; defaults to the first option and colors that one even though it isn't the one I clicked.  Digging around the code some more, there are some preloader() and `if(data.is_chosen_refresh) render = true;` calls in the js. My exp. with js is minimal at best; is this a 'literal' refresh of the element? If so, I'd imagine this is what's causing the difficulty.  Would there be a workaround?